# how to catch multiple transaction error and set it to output parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL programming. I have write the following sub program to implement two transactions. I need to use three output parameter to record the error. I need to initially set `@P_Return_Status = 'S'`.

If On error, in the CATCH block, I need to ROLLBACK the transaction; `Set @P_Return_Status = ‘E’;Set @P_Error_Code = Error_Number();Set @P_Error_Messages = Error_Message()`

How could I output the error for multiple (here is two) transactions and being caught by the main program. Forgive me if my code are totally wrong since I am very new to T-SQL.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sub_Initialize') IS NULL -- check if SP Exist
EXE('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sub_Initialize AS SET NOCOUNT ON;')
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sub_Initialize 
(
@P_CurrentPeriod VARCHAR(12)
@P_Return_Status VARCHAR(1) OUT,
@P_Error_Code INT OUT,
@P_Error_Messages VARCHAR(2000) OUT
)   
AS
BEGIN

SET @P_Return_Status VARCHAR(1) = 'S'
SET @P_Error_Code INT = NULL
SET @P_Error_Messages VARCHAR(2000) = NULL

BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Rollup_Elemental_Costs WHERE Rpt_Period    = @P_CurrentPeriod)
    DELETE FROM Rollup_Elemental_Costs
    WHERE Rpt_Period = @P_CurrentPeriod
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
SET @P_Return_Status = ‘E’
SET @P_Error_Code = ERROR_CODE()
SET @P_Error_Messages = ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Rollup_Batch_Detail_Trx WHERE Rpt_Period = @P_CurrentPeriod)
    DELETE FROM Rollup_Batch_Detail_Trx
    WHERE Rpt_Period = @P_CurrentPeriod
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
SET @P_Return_Status = 'E'
SET @P_Error_Code = ERROR_NUMBER()
SET @P_Error_Messages = ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a table for storing error messages. Then insert each transaction error message into the table so that you can query the error table later to find out the error messages in transaction.

```
Create table error_Message
(
Transaction_identification Varchar(20) --To identify which trans generated error message
Return_Status VARCHAR(1),
Error_Code INT,
Error_Messages VARCHAR(2000) 
)
```

You may have to add some more columns to identify transaction details

**Note :** If you don't want to store error messages in physical table then convert the same to temp table inside procedure. Then at the end of procedure you can return the temp table results

Then inside `CATCH` block you can insert into the `error_Message` table

```
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
Insert into error_Message(Transaction_identification,Return_Status,Error_Code,Error_Me
select 'Trans 1',‘E’,ERROR_CODE(),ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```